# Can't delete folders in contents of Mac .app whose names contain a certain character

Tags: macos, terminal

Using Mac OS 12.3.1 but have limited experience working at the terminal.

I've written an .app using Python and Pyinstaller. It works fine, but for certain reasons, I need to delete folders within the PyQt5 directory of the application bundle that contain a period in their name. Typing

```
find my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5 -name "*.*" -type d
```

shows me the correct folders, but after trying

```
find my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5 -name "*.*" -type d -delete
```

and reopening my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5, I still see the folders present. I must be missing something simple here.

Comment: You could try `find my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5 -name "*.*" | xargs rmdir` to remove all these directories a slightly different way. It's ok if it yells at you about trying to rmdir files that match `"*.*"`, only the directories will be deleted.

Comment: Hmm. That didn't seem to work for me. The unwanted directories are till there.

Comment: I should have mentioned that some of the unwanted directories are a couple levels down so to speak within PyQt5, e.g. one is located in PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQml, another is in PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick, etc.

Answer (score 0):

find my_app.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5 -name "*.*" -type d -exec rm -r {} +

appears to work.